# How did Toomas Hendrik Ilves get US citizenship and where/when/why did he give it up? (former president of Estonia and curious character)

Tags: united-states, president, citizenship, estonia

The question [Do foreign heads of state or government have to give up a US citizenship if they have it?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/42380/16047) reminded me of the curious character [Toomas Hendrik Ilves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toomas_Hendrik_Ilves), "...an Estonian politician who served as the fourth president of Estonia from 2006 until 2016."

> Ilves was born in Stockholm, Sweden; his parents Endel Ilves (1923–1991) and Irene Ilves (née Rebane; 1925–2018) fled Estonia after its occupation by the Soviet Union during World War II. His maternal grandmother was a Russian from Saint Petersburg. He grew up in the United States in Leonia, New Jersey, and graduated from Leonia High School in 1972 as valedictorian. He received a bachelor's degree in psychology from Columbia University in 1976 and a master's degree in the same subject from the University of Pennsylvania in 1978. He also received an honorary degree from St. Olaf College in 2014 in recognition of his relationship with the college. In addition to Estonian, Ilves also speaks English, German, Latvian and Spanish. By Ilves's own admission, he speaks Estonian with a comparatively strong American accent, on account of spending his formative and young adult years in America and Germany.

He shows up on Wikipedia's [Former United States citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Former_United_States_citizens)

**Question:** How did Toomas Hendrik Ilves get US citizenship and where/when/why did he give it up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*How did Toomas Hendrik Ilves get US citizenship and where/when/why did he give it up?*

From the Estonian Wikipedia article, *[Toomas Hendrik Ilves](https://et.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toomas_Hendrik_Ilves#Elulugu)*, **<sup>[1]</sup>**

> [Toomas Hendrik Ilves] family moved to the United States in 1957. In 1962, they became US citizens. Toomas Hendrik Ilves also had US citizenship until April 1, 1993, when he renounced it.

Ilves renounced his US citizenship to become the "Ambassador of Estonia to the United States in 1993, also serving as Ambassador to Canada and Mexico at the same time." **<sup>[2]</sup>** **<sup>[3]</sup>**

Apparently, Ilves received his US citizenship in 1962 along with his parents through derivative naturalization.

Being three at the time of his immigration to the US, Ilves could not qualify for application to US citizenship (minimum age is 18). However, there is a process known as [derivative naturalization](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-h-chapter-4) under the former INA 321, which was applicable between 1952 and early 2001. (The law was changed in 2000 moving derivative naturalization to INA 320.)

> In general, a child born outside of the United States to two noncitizen parents, or ..., acquires citizenship under former INA 321 if:
>
> - The child’s parent(s) meet one of the following conditions:
>
> > - Both parents naturalize; ...
>
> - The child is under 18 years of age when his or her parent(s) naturalize; and
> - The child is residing in the United States pursuant to a lawful admission for permanent residence at the time the parent(s) naturalized or thereafter begins to reside permanently in the United States.

---

**<sup>1</sup>** Minor editing was done to the automated English translation of the quote.

**<sup>2</sup>** Wikipedia, [Toomas Hendrik Ilves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toomas_Hendrik_Ilves#Career)

**<sup>3</sup>** *See*, Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations (1961), [Article 8](https://legal.un.org/ilc/texts/instruments/english/conventions/9_1_1961.pdf#page=4).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_citizenship) claims: "Both the former Estonian president Toomas Hendrik Ilves and the former Lithuanian president Valdas Adamkus had been naturalized US citizens prior to assuming their offices. Both have renounced their US citizenships: Ilves in 1993 and Adamkus in 1998."

Comment: [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/nov/03/president-ilves-made-estonia) reported: "In 1993, Ilves formally renounced his US citizenship – a job requirement – and relocated to Washington DC."

Comment: [Estonian Review](https://vm.ee/sites/default/files/content-editors/web-static/085/ER_37.pdf), Vol. 16, No. 37, Sep 20 – 26, 2006: "After returning to Estonia and relinquishing his US citizenship, Ilves served as Estonia's ambassador to the United States from 1993-1996."

Comment: Derivative naturalization seems unlikely. 
 If his parents had to have lived in the US for 5 years before naturalizing, which is the normal minimum period of residence today, Ilves must have naturalized independently after reaching the age of majority.

Comment: The [Estonian Wikipedia](https://et.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toomas_Hendrik_Ilves) claims: "Pere kolis Ameerika Ühendriikidesse 1957. aastal. 1962. aastal said nad USA kodanikeks." --> Google Translate --> "The family moved to the United States in 1957. In 1962, they became U.S. citizens." That would make the English Wikipedia's accounting incorrect: Ilves was *four* years old when the family moved to the US.

Comment: The [Great Norwegian Encyclopedia](https://snl.no/Toomas_Hendrik_Ilves) states: "Familien Ilves flyttet i 1957 til USA og ble i 1962 amerikanske statsborgere." --> Google Translate --> "The Ilves family moved to the United States in 1957 and became American citizens in 1962."

Comment: @njuffa - Actually, three years old, Toomas was born in December 1953. He didn't turn four until December 26, 1957.

Comment: @Rick Smith: I stand corrected, I had simply subtracted: 1957 - 1953. My comments were intended to support the answer by showing it is very plausible considering the timeline. FWIW, the Estonian Wikipedia provides a precise date of April 1, 1993 for the renunciation of US citizenship.

Comment: @njuffa - A clue that thirteen was the wrong age is that Ilves doesn't claim to speak Swedish, which he likely would have learned had he lived in Sweden for thirteen years.

Comment: @phoog - The Politico article was in error. Ilves was three, not thirteen, when he immigrated to the US.

Comment: It would be useful to note *why* becoming an ambassador is linked to renouncing citizenship - the Vienna convention on diplomatic relationships (https://legal.un.org/ilc/texts/instruments/english/conventions/9_1_1961.pdf) article 8 frowns upon (although does not totally prohibit) foreign countries appointing local citizens as diplomatic staff.

Comment: @Peteris: Estonia also has pretty complicated laws sometimes forbidding dual citizenship, and sometimes not. I have no clue what was in force in 1993-1996 in that regard (esp. for government officials).