# Are there many high level political appointees who have served two countries in quick succession?

Tags: united-states, banking, political-appointments

[Stanley Fischer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Fischer) was the 8th governor of the Bank of Israel. His tenure ended in 2013.
Very soon afterwards, he was appointed the Vice Chair of the (US) Federal Reserve, holding this post from 2014 to 2017.

Are there other examples of high level political appointees serving in two separate countries in quick succession? If not, what made this case unique?

Comment: *political appointee* is probably incorrect term here - it is a government job, but there's nothing political about it. E.g., it is not uncommon for train engineers retire in France and work for a few more years in Germany (where the retirement age is higher, especially in this profession.)

Comment: Football coaches for national teams are another high-profile case, like Guus Heddink or Zidane.

Comment: @RogerV.political appointee in the sense of someone who is directly appointed by the head of state or other high ranking politician. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_appointments_in_the_United_States)

Comment: This definition is specific to the US - it is worth specifying this in the question. In many places *political* would mean that their job depends on their allégeance to a certain political party/policy, or at least to the country. The head of the central bank  is like a corporation executive - it provides qualified services to whoever is their employer

Comment: What is a *political appointee* internationally speaking?

Comment: @RogerV. : The Wikipedia page might be US-specific, but the idea certainly isn't. For instance, Belgium also has high-level political appointees. In fact, outside the US they're far easier to define: government officials who can be (and usually are) dismissed at will by newly elected politicians. Regular civil servants are hard to dismiss, so the distinction is fairly clear.

Comment: @MSalters *government officials who can be (and usually are) dismissed at will by newly elected politicians* - the procedures for appointing Federal reserve board members are not unlike those for appointing the Supreme Court Judges - they are nominated by the executive, but have to be approved by the Congress, and cannot be dismissed at will. The idea is that they are maximally independent from the political pressures.

Comment: Probably doesn't count as "political appointee", but king Henri III of France, having no hope to inherit the french throne as he was fourth in line of succession, managed to get himself elected king of Poland. He reigned for 2 years before, all of his older brothers having died, he became king of France and gave up the polish throne.

Comment: I'd imagine it's not uncommon in education/academia where positions such as heads of state universities and institutes, heads of funding bodies, heads of boards concerned with standards and accreditation, etc, may be appointed by the state, but people will have international careers.

Comment: do ancient military examples count? Hannibal was a general in Carthage (and later became a politician and was elected to the highest office of the Carthaginian state) before going on to be an Admiral for the Seleucids. Alicibiades also served Athens, before defecting to their enemy to serve as a military advisor for Sparta and later various Persian satraps (before eventually being recalled and prosecuted in Athens). There are doubtless also countless Medieval examples, although the extent to which many of them held a specific office may not always be clear

Comment: Political strategist [Lynton Crosbie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynton_Crosby) held positions in both Australian and the UK, as well as shorter appointments in Sri Lanka and New Zealand. I'm not sure if chief election strategist or similar would meet the OP's definition.

Comment: indirectly related: [Do foreign heads of state or government have to give up a US citizenship if they have it?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/42380/16047) and [How did Toomas Hendrik Ilves get US citizenship and where/when/why did he give it up? (former president of Estonia and curious character)](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/73003/16047)

Comment: Voting not to close - This is a question concerning political appointments which is topical here. Political appointments don't just mean that a head of a state can directly appoint someone. It also includes positions where a government has a process of [vetting](https://www.historicalindex.org/in-politics-what-does-vetting-mean.htm) before appointing someone. This obviously is especially important when appointing a foreign or dual-national citizen to such posts, which is what the Q is also about.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Mark Carney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Carney) was the governor of the Bank of Canada from 2008 to 2013, and then governor of the Bank of England from 2013 to 2020. These are not "political appointments" in the US sense, but the relevant politicians definitely have influence over the appointments.

Answer (score 19):

[Mikheil Saakashvili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikheil_Saakashvili) served as the President of Georgia from 2008 till 2013, then as the Governor of Odessa (in Ukraine) from 2015 to 2016.

Comment: Neither President nor Governor is a political appointee. I assume that both are elected.

Comment: @political_noob, as I recall, the latter is an appointment in Ukraine.

Answer (score 7):

I wonder if that counts, but [Robert Kocharyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Kocharyan)

> He served as the President of the Nagorno-Karabakh Republic from 1994 to 1997 and Prime Minister of Nagorno-Karabakh from 1992 to 1994. He served as the second President of Armenia between 1998 and 2008 and as Prime Minister of Armenia from 1997 to 1998

Answer (score 4):

While they were elected instead of appointed positions, [Sam Houston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Houston) held office in two countries:

- Republic of Texas (President 1836-38 & 1841-44, House of Representatives 1839-41)
- United States of America (Representative [TN] 1823-27, Governor [TN] 1827-29, Senator [TX] 1846-59, Governor [TX] 1859-61)

Had Houston not been forced to resign as Governor for refusing to swear an oath to the Confederate States of America, he would have served under **three** countries.

This kind of thing probably happens often whenever a piece of territory changes hands between countries.

Comment: All of those are elected offices and not appointments.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question:**
>
> Are there many high level political appointees who have served two countries in quick succession?

**Rahm Emanuel**, served in the Israeli Defense Force in 1991.

- Current U.S. Ambassador to Japan
- Former White House Chief of Staff
- Former Senior advisor to the President

Comment: He didn’t serve in the IDF, he was just a summer volunteer one year.

Comment: how is serving in an army a political appointment of any kind?

Comment: @dEmigOd read the question,  it’s simple logic.  He is a political appointee in the US who served Israel’s IDF.  The question doesn’t require one to be a political appointee in the second country just service.

Comment: @JonathanReez  He served the IDF, twice.